# mysql BLOB manipulate in php

Tags: php, mysql, blob

In mysql, I have a db column with `BLOB` data type.

The blob data looks something like this:

```
{\"Name\":\"Mike Smith\",\"Number\":\"1\"}
```

or

```
[{\"Name\":\"Mike Smith\"},{\"Name\":\"Jon Doe\",\"Spaces\":\"1\"},{\"Name\":\"My Space(s)\"},{\"Name\":\"Rear\"}]
```

I am trying to detect the content in php and saving the string as a variable as such:

```
{\"Name\":\"Mike Smith\",\"Number\":\"1\"} 
BECOMES -> Mike Smith(1)
```

And...

```
[{\"Name\":\"Mike Smith\"},{\"Name\":\"Jon Doe\",\"Number\":\"1\"},{\"Name\":\"My Space(s)\"},{\"Name\":\"Rear\"}]   
BECOMES --> Mike Smith, Jon Doe(1), My Space(s), Rear
```

I am not familiar with BLOB data type and wanted to get some help from the community. How would I manipulate the BLOB data to above?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: That looks like JSON data. Why not just parse it with the various [JSON functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)?

Comment: You might be right. I am going to give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$data = '[{\"Name\":\"Mike Smith\"},{\"Name\":\"Jon Doe\",\"Number\":\"1\"},
{\"Name\":\"My Space(s)\"},{\"Name\":\"Rear\"}]';

$data =  json_decode(stripslashes($data))  ;

 $string = '';
 for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($data) ; $i++) { 

 $d = $data[$i];

 if(isset($d->Number)){
    $number = '('.$d->Number.')';
 }
 else{
    $number = '';
 }

 $string .= ($d->Name).$number.',  ';

}


echo $string;
```